# In ROBOT Framework, Using user defined Java Library instead of it's own :FOR LOOP

Tags: java, list, arraylist, robotframework

Im having a situation on how to bring the user defined java library keywords rather than using ROBOT framework's own for loop. i.e. im writing a common code through which i store a list of elements and clicking a specific element which contains a specific text.

As a first step I'm trying to just display the text of elements in the list. It worked using :FOR LOOP of RF. Its shown below

```
@{customers}  get webelements  ${customer_list}
:FOR  ${items}    IN    @{customers}
\    ${customer_names}=    Get Text    ${items}
\    click element  ${items}
\    sleep  2s
\    Log    ${items}
```

Now i need to replace this FOR by the below keyword called "Store Names",

```
@{customers}  get webelements  ${customer_list}
${items}  Store Names  @{customers}
get text  ${items}
Log  ${items}

OUTPUT: 20170302 09:35:26.404 : FAIL : ValueError: Element locator '{items}' did not match any elements.
```

Below is the JAVA code for your reference, the below variable 'text' has no link with variable 'iterator'. I don't know how to bring this. I badly need of someone's help since i went through several blogs of conversation but none having situation like this.

```
public class StoreElements {
public static final String ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL";

public void storeNames(List<String> text){
     // Print the name from the list....
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

//add elements to list
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Object eleNames = iterator.next();

  }
 }
}
```

I have corrected the code and but when executed, i got the below error. Please help me.

Corrected code:

```
public class StoreElements<WebElement> {
public static final String ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL";
public void storeNamesofElements(WebElement text){
     // Print the name from the list....
List<WebElement> list = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
//add elements to list
Iterator<WebElement> iterator = list.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    text=iterator.next();
}}}
```

Error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'elements' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You're trying to use the return value of `storeNames`, but `storeNames` doesn't seem to be returning anything. Also, the way you are using it, it should be returning a single locator.

Comment: Thanks for your response Bryan Oakley! I have corrected my code as to return the 'text' values and got an error again.Updated the corrected code and the error above. Kindly help me.

Comment: The error you list appears to be a python error, but you've only shown java code.

Comment: The code is already available shown above. So didnt specify here. For your information,                                                                                                                                                 @{customers}  get webelements  ${customer_list}                                       
${items}  Store Names of Elements  @{customers}                                                               
get text  ${items}                                                                                                            
Log  ${items}